# I want to sort the array by keys in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array, `$data`, in the form of :

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [group_exp] => Group 2
            [cat_exp] => Category 3
            [sub_exp] => Sub Category 4
        )
    [2] => Array
       (
            [group_exp] => Group 3
            [cat_exp] => Category 4
            [sub_exp] => Sub Category 5
       )

)
```

but i want to save this array in this form :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [group_exp] => Group 2
            [cat_exp] => Category 3
            [sub_exp] => Sub Category 4
        )
    [1] => Array
       (
            [group_exp] => Group 3
            [cat_exp] => Category 4
            [sub_exp] => Sub Category 5
       )

)
```

Comment: hi, i want the values of $data[1] become $data[0] and values of $data[2] become $data[1]

Comment: Is your problem just that you want the indexes shifted 1 down? or are the indexes all over the place?

Comment: `array_values()`. If you didn't know that - you could simply use `foreach` or even `for`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php

Comment: could you plse send me the code in answer ????

Comment: You're actually saying you just want to rebuild the array keys? What you're asking is not ordering, it's a key re-indexation.

Comment: okay allendar. my mistake. :(

Comment: @Rakesh Kumar: "could you plse send me the code in answer" --- my advice to you as a programming and stackoverflow.com newbie - please **STOP** it. It's a community for developers, not a charity. If you want to grow professionally - start learning. You will learn **nothing** if you don't try anything yourself. And, no, just looking how other people write code is unlikely will help you become a better developer.

Comment: @Rakesh Kumar: that's my whole point. You've got a solution, but you haven't got any experience. So you are still there where you have been 20 minutes ago.

Comment: Rakesh, in the future just know that there's a [long list of functions to choose from](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php), so you can find what matches what you need.

Comment: i did that on php.net but was not finding the right one which to use...thats why i posted question here. thanks all for you time. really appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments has shown, use `array_values` to reorder the indexes if the array already is in the correct order.

```
$array = array_values($array);
```

If the array should be sorted by its indices (if their inherent order is not sorted, such as [2], [1], [3], sort the array by key first:

```
ksort($array);
$array = array_values($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to reduce your indexes by one, rather than all the way to zero, consider using a `for` loop approach:

```
$length = count($data);
for($i = 1; $i <= $length; $i++){
    $data[$i-1] = $data[$i];
    unset($data[$i]);
}
```